# Upgrading to the latest mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, upgrade, database

Basically I want you to help me upgrade mongodb so I could use the new methods in 3.2 such as `db.collection.insertMany()`.

`mongod --version` prints out `db version v2.6.6`

I use windows 7 .. 64

I have a mongodb folder in my c drive folder

and in the mongodb folder I have the `bin` folder and the `data` folder

I Think the data folder holds my dbs and the db's data. I cant actually open a file db/ filestore.ns to check.(it's just 0s) I'm just under the impression that that is where the data is.

So I'm wondering if I remove the whole `data` folder and place that temporarily on the desktop and delete the whole mongodb folder in my c drive then download it from [here](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production) it would be OK. what I mean by that is that the download will give me the mongodb folder in my c drive and if it's not there I will put it there. **I just realized that I have a data folder inside my c drive folder also. that data folder  has a db folder and inside that I have documents that have  names similar to the dbs I'm working with** so I guess that will be the one I'm placing on my desktop.

so if I do that will I get the mongod and mongo shell updated and if I place the data folder that I put on the desktop next to the new downloaded mongodb will I still be able to use the dbs I was working with?

Also I'm not sure what windows 64 bit 2008 R2 is but I think that is the one I should be downloading I don't think they had the 2008 R2 at the end, the last time I downloaded mongodb so I'm getting confused I have a 64 bit OS.

I hope it's easy as the way I described. I want to make a smooth transition. That's why I'm asking you smart guys.

And I want to keep the variable paths. Right now I could be in any directory in the cmd and do mongod and start an instance. that's because it's on a path I think and I dont want to mess with that convenience

Answer (score 0):

What I mentioned above works. I just want to tell people if you download the MSI the mongoDB folders goes into your `program files` folder. I took it out from there and put it into my c drive put my data folder in there too and I was able to retrieve the data. I get this message now when I start mongo.

`2016-02-04T00:17:09.889-0800 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later updateis not installed, will zero-out data files MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1` I read this might be a problem with the way I put the data folder. but I think I set it up right and I see the new DBs being put into the data/db folder